# Is it possible to write to a remote HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

As title, is it possible to write to a remote HDFS?

E.g. I have installed a HDFS cluster on AWS EC2, and I want to write a file from my local computer to the HDFS cluster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways you could write to remote HDFS,

- Use the `WebHDFS api` available.It supports the systems running outside
  Hadoop clusters to access and manipulate the HDFS contents. It
  doesn't require the client systems to have hadoop binaries installed.
- Configure the client system as `Hadoop edge node` to interact with the
  Hadoop cluster/HDFS.

Please refer,

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/webhdfs.html

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/edge-nodes-in-hadoop-clusters.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just want to further the discussion. From http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html, "A client request to create a file does not reach the NameNode immediately. In fact, initially the HDFS client caches the file data into a temporary local file.", is it the reason why client can't just write directly to remote HDFS? As such, it must be within the HDFS cluster.

Comment: yes , almost..The client which connects to the `remote HDFS` should know the configuration details of it beforehand , so that it can split the file into blocks as per hdfs conf, and would write to HDFS as specified in the **Staging** topic in the above link. This is what would happen when you configure `edge node` and when you use `hadoop dfs` commands.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to make my local client be part of the HDFS cluster? So a DataNode will run on my local client?

Comment: no, edge node is just a gateway to hadoop cluster which just know how to connect/interact with the configured hadoop cluster.No hadoop daemons will run in the edge node, its just a client. But if you going to just perform few HDFS manipulation operations then `WebHDFS` will be the best choice.